# Help with using the knife tool

Tags: modeling, edges, knife-tool

I've been working on a Blender tutorial for making a pencil, and I'm trying to use a knife tool for a part of it. I want to create a new loop that goes around the outside of the model, but it doesn't despite having Toggle X-Ray on. However, that also makes a duplicate of the half-loop above it, which bothers me. What do I do?

Comment: Post some screenshots for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing K on Edit Mode you can see at the bottom of your blender window every shortcut you can press to have the desired cut. What you are looking for is pressing K first and then Z to cut through. Every tool has many choices that you can see at the bottom of the window when you press the corresponding key.

Comment: I mistook the line of dots in the middle of the new faces for another edge loop, sorry.